# R: Create an object in a for loop nested in sapply to count cases

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes. For each of these dataframes I want to do computations that involve only specific rows and columns. These computations use a for loop that counts the number of cases for a specific number range and stores this number in an object called `counter`.

The code works if I apply it to just one of the dataframes.

```
counter=0
for (val in df[7,10:109]) {
  if (val <= 5000 & val !=-1) {counter=counter+1}
  else {break}
}
```

Now I want it to calculate the same for all the dataframes. I tried this using the `sapply` function:

```
counter=0
sapply(filelist, function(x){
x<-get(x)
  for (val in x[7,10:109]) {
    if (val <= 5000 & val !=-1) {counter=counter+1}
    else {break}
    print(counter)
  }
})
```

However, the results of the computation are not saved in the counter. When I include the `print(counter)` command I can see that the results are in fact saved for each of the data frames temporarily.
How do I have them added up in one object that I can then manipulate further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not look optimal, but if you run `sapply` on a `filelist` you should expect getting back a vector of counts.  So you may try returning the count from each call in `sapply`, and then assigning it to a variable:

```
results <- sapply(filelist, function(x) {
    x <- get(x)
    counter <- 0
    for (val in x[7,10:109]) {
        if (val <= 5000 & val !=-1) {counter=counter+1}
        else {break}
        print(counter)
    }
    return(counter)
})
```